# How do I set the height of the preview cells in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, swift

When my UITableView is loading/doesn't have any cells in it yet the cells seem to be set to 44pt high. Can I customize this so it's set to a higher amount, perhaps 100pt?

Comment: Doesn't returning a value in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` increase the size of the preview cells?

Comment: @user3746428 Doesn't matter if there are no cells yet, so no index paths to give heights for. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in IB as well as programtically

In IB Select UITableView and in attribute inspector set the Row Height as per your need. Select UITableViewCell and in Size Inspector set height as per your need.

If you want to do it programtically, do it using heightForRowAtIndexPath and return 100.0;

Comment: I don't want static cell heights, though, I want Auto Layout to determine them dynamically. But I do want the previews to be a certain size.

Comment: Suppose you hav a uilabel which height changes dynamically on the basis of text it contains. you hav to consider 2 things first is constrsints, apply top, left, Bottom, right, width height constraints(height wud b >=) second in heughtForRowAtIndexpath calculate height of the text you are assigning to uilabel with respect to the font size and return this calculated size.

Answer (score 0):

You try this one:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 100.0f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no rows to display yet, set the UITableView's property .rowHeight like so:

```
tableView.rowHeight = 100.0f;
```